# What kind of database is used in Android document call functions?

Tags: android, database

Okay, so I am still learning to do some coding here, and I seem to have gotten stuck.

I want to have a select number of documents added to a package for the Android OS
but I don't know how to store said documents. Do I add them all under res/raw, or make an SQLite database and call from there?

More importantly, I need to be able to call those documents when a search criteria is added.

I was on the Android reference site, and they add write functions for the SQLite db, which I would prefer not having as an option.

What kind of database should I implement here?
I would prefer a link to an example, but anything would help at this point.

Comment: How does one "call" a "document"? Without a clearer picture of what you are trying to do here, it will be difficult for anyone to give you help.

Comment: well, i mean pull a document, similar to displaying an image for a user. so to a degree, they select something from a filter, and the documents are pulled or called from the database. im at work and dont have the code on me at the moment, but its like (ex) showing a list of songs being filtered by artist (to that degree)

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this. 
[Notepad example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)

> or make an SQLlite database and call from there?

No you don't create a SQLlite database it will be created for you after your App start the database call. 
[See this SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)
And [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)